# Why I recive message "502 bad gateway" when I try to deploy my wordpress app

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

I use a docker-compose file to deploy my wordpress app togheter with mysql

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpAdmin
    restart: always
    ports: 
        - 3333:80
    environment: 
        PMA_HOST: db
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

and this is my .travis.yml file

```
services:
  - docker

script:
  - echo 'test complete'

after_succes:
    - docker-compose up -d

deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  region: us-east-2
  app: demo-licenta
  env: Demolicenta-env
  bucket_name: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-836810127342
  bucket_path: licenta_demo
  on:
    branch: master
  acces_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

The app works fine locally when I run docker-compose up -d. I've checked my logs on AWS and I don't find any warnings or errors. The app health is OK in the beginning, but after a few moments becomes severe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup logging in Elastic Beanstalk and check the error in logs. 502 is backend failure, so it could mean DB failure as well as PHP errors, and without logs it's hard to tell.

[How to set up logging is EB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html)